# mysql: Optimizing query w/ mixed-ascendency ORDER BY

Tags: database, mysql, query-optimization, innodb

I have a large table (~1M rows now, soon ~10M) that has two ranked columns (in addition to the regular data):

- `avg_visited`, a float 0-1 representing a %age popularity; higher is better
- `alexa_rank`, an integer 1-N giving an a priori ranking

The a priori ranking is from external sources so can't be changed. Many rows have no popularity yet (as no user has yet hit it), so the a priori ranking is the fallback ordering. The popularity however does change very frequently - both to update old entries and to add a popularity to ones that previously only had the a priori ranking, if some user actually hits it.

I frequently run `SELECT id, url, alexa_rank, avg_visited FROM`sites`ORDER BY avg_visited desc, alexa_rank asc LIMIT 49500, 500` (for various values of 49500).

However, ORDER BY cannot use an index with mixed ascendency per http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

This is in mysql 5.1, innodb.

How can I best change this situation to give me a sane, fully indexed query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `MySQL` does not support `DESC` clauses in the indexes, neither does it support indexes on derived expressions.

You can store the negative popularity along with the positive one and use it in the `ORDER BY`:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_mytable_negpopularity_apriori ON (neg_popularity, a_priori);

INSERT
INTO    mytable (popularity, neg_popularity)
VALUES  (@popularity, -@popularity);

SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
ORDER BY
        neg_popularity, a_priori
```

Comment: That's the first thing I thought of too. I'm wondering if there's a nicer solution.

Comment: @Sai: it's hardly probable (with `MySQL`). In other engines, you can create an index on `(popularity DESC, a_priori)`, but not in `MySQL`.

Comment: Also, FWIW, I have to use a covering index - i.e. on `(neg_popularity, a_priori, common_data_1, common_data2)` - because a simple index does not work with order by if there are other fields in the select. :-/

Comment: @Sai: a simple index works with `ORDER BY` alright. It's the optimizer that can be reluctant to use it for some reason, but you can force its usage with `FORCE INDEX`. Do you have a `LIMIT` clause in your query? Could you please post the full query?

Comment: I *always* use LIMIT. Full query added to question.

Comment: @Sai: For higher values of `49500` sorting can be faster than traversing the index.

Answer (score 1):

Just a simple hack:

Since since popularity is a float between 0 to 1.  You can multiply it by -1 and the number will be between -1 to 0.

This way you can reverse the sort order of popularity to `ORDER BY popularity ASC, a_priori ASC`

Not sure the overhead out weighs the gain.

This reminds me of the hack of storing emails in reverse form.

Comment: This is identical to Quassnoi's, so I'm giving him the check for being first (unless someone comes up with a better solution).

What hack of storing emails in reverse form? I don't know it.